# Blender crashes when decimating hi-poly mesh

Tags: modifiers, objects, polycount

I just recieved a terrain mesh with over 16M polys.
I can open it and mess around the scene quite well since I'm on a really decent PC.
But I'm trying to decimate it (using the modifier itself) and my PC just crashes. It gets stuck for a while and then the sound and signal dies and PC freezes forever.
I haven't tried letting it frozen for more than 10min but since the sound on the PC dies I'm assuming it won't get out of the dead lock.

I don't think I'm recieving a less hi-poly version of that mesh, so I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Decimating can be quite intensive both in CPU and RAM usage. For that amount of polygons it can take quite some time and hug all the resources of your computer making it seem like it has crashed, but it is possible that it is just working hard at the task.10 mins might not be enough to complete the action. Try leaving the process overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionnal of Doyousketch2's answer, try to split your mesh on multiple objects, by using Separate by Loosing part or Knife tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the newest release of Blender.
Recalculate normals, then try *Clean up* options on the mesh.
Maybe you'll have more luck that way than through the modifier.

[image: Dissolve]